# What is the use of &amp; in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

In my XML, I found something like this:

```
<str_pair key="1" value="&amp;1 Orange" />
```

I'm just curious what is the use for `&amp;`?

Also, when I bind the whole value(`&amp;1 Orange`) to a WPF menu and I run the windows application, the menu will show the whole value included the `&amp;`.

If I run the compiled/published app, will the `&amp;` disappeared from the menu?

Comment: I guess you could maybe try running and seeing if it disappears?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I tried already, it still there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&amp;` is simply the encoded version of the "&" (ampersand) character.

So yes, the entry you see represents the "&" character.

From [W3C XML 1.0 Spec, section 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters... If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " & " and " < " respectively.

Comment: Not HTML encoded since this is XML and WPF has nothing to do with rendering HTML

Comment: Apologies for sloppiness. The ampersand character is used for entity declarations in XML as well as HTML, so if you literally want the ampersand character it must be escaped as `&amp;`. See [W3C XML 1.0 Spec, section 2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)