# Write a commercial AND '&' in a XML Attribute using jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I try to use Jackson 2.13.3 in Java to get the following XML output.

```
<Property name="11&22">
  <test>11&22</test>
</Property>
```

but I can't get the & sign in the attribute to display correctly. This is what I get:

```
<Property name="11&amp;22">
  <test>11&22</test>
</Property>
```

Has somebody a glue how I can get the desired output?

Here a MVP (Note that I already tried to use @JsonRawValue, but it only works on Properties and not on Attributes):

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestXML</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Property.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

public class Property {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "name")
  @JsonRawValue
  String name = "11&22";

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "test")
  @JsonRawValue
  String test = "11&22";
}
```

Main.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(new Property()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129614/what-is-the-use-of-amp-in-xml) and it's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31129660/2838289).

Comment: You're trying to generate invalid XML and no XML tool will allow you to do that.